# Nativescript Delete a Class

Tags: nativescript

I'm using NativeScript 5 Core

I figured out how to add a class to an element with javascript:
Selected the element (a label) using getViewById, then

```
//Add Best Class
uilabelname.className = "best";
```

But, I can't figure out how to delete a class!
I don't want to set it to "", but rather, delete a specific class.
Add the "best" class and then be able to delete "best" in another function.

XML:

```
<Label id="lblRny1a" row="1" col="0" class="text-center rny" text="{{rny1a}}" textWrap="true" />
```

Comment: XML:  <Label id="lblRny1a" row="1" col="0" class="text-center rny" text="{{rny1a}}" textWrap="true" />  JS:  lblRny1a.className = "best";  Want to add and remove a class without having to set the entire class list string, if possible, as stated by @Manoj.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use multiple class names on `className` separated by space. When you want to remove a class, just remove that item from string and update `className` back.

**Example**

```
label.className = "class1 class2";

 // or 

label.className = "class2";
```

Comment: Thank you, that will work. I was hoping I could add/remove class names on an element like in vanilla JS: label.classList.add("class1"); or  label.classList.remove("class1"); instead of having to replace the whole class list. Possible?

Comment: This is how [className](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/blob/46705ee33278e8f9ec04b00ea592dd65ba855e74/tns-core-modules/ui/core/view-base/view-base.ts#L1016-L1021) is handled internally, so if you like to have it as an array modify the `cssClasses` property and call `._onCssStateChange()` method. But I would recommend just sticking to class name as there won't be any difference between these methodologies.

Comment: Appreciate the help. Just learning NativeScript, so far only a few glitches!